# What order are fields initialized in?

Tags: java, initialization

I read this question while studying model questions for exams.

```
class Was
{
    private int a=show();
    private int b=5;
    private int show()
    {
        return b;
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println((new Was()).a);
    }
}
```

I compiled this,it prints as 0. Why it is not print as '5' ?

Comment: Because the initializers are evaluated in the order they appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Field initialization happens when a constructor is invoked and in order of declaration. This field

```
private int a=show();
```

is initialized before

```
private int b=5;
```

It is initialized with the value returned by `show()`. At that time `b` has yet to be initialized to `5`. Its default value is `0`. So `show()` returns `0`. That value is assigned to `a`.

Comment: Thank you @Sotirios Delimanolis.But,at the time of calling show(), b is unknown field,how it can be returned?

Comment: @anavaraslamurep The field is known, it has just been given the default value for `int` primitives, which is `0`.

Comment: Java object fields go through two steps. Before any constructor or initializer execution, each is initialized to a default value that depends only on its type, 0 for numeric fields, null for references, false for booleans. That value can be changed later by an initializer or by constructor code.

Answer (score 1):

```
private int a=show();
```

By the time you calling `show()` method the value of `b` not yet set and hence the default value of integer is `0`  results.

To see desired output

```
private int b=5;
private int a=show();
```